# Incorrect return from shell_exec

Tags: php, bash, exec

I'm trying to figure out how many lines exist in a CSV I'm about to iterate over so I can monitor progress.

From the command line, this gives the correct value:

```
cat /path/to/CA_MA.csv | perl -p -i -e "s/^M/\n/g" | wc -l
```

However, using [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/shell_exec), I get nothing back:

```
trim( shell_exec( "cat /path/to/CA_MA.csv | perl -p -i -e 's/^M/\n/g' | wc -l" ) )
```

I've tried both STDOUT and STDERR (`... 2>&1`). and I've tried this from my script from the interactive console (`php -a`).

Comment: Maybe I dumb suggest but...can't you use file_get_contents() and count the new lines? Or maybe use file() and count the element of the returned array?

Comment: I'm almost sure you don't need to process the `^M` chars AND  `wc -l < /path/to/CA_MA.csv` will echo just the line count. Why you're not seeing any results in php shell_exec is outside of my experience. Did you try searching for tag=php shell_exec? I'm almost sure there is another function call that I have seen mentioned in this regard, i.e. shell_execv() or similar. Good luck.

Comment: why don't you use the pipeview (pv) utility to monitor progress ?

Comment: @shellter If I don't process the ^M, I get a `wc -l` result of 1 on the command line. There are other shell/system functions, but I get the same result with all.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa To be honest, I didn't try that. The line ending are all fubar so I probably assumed I'd need to do more. I'll try this approach. Thanks.

Comment: @bunting I don't know anything about `pv`. I'll look that up.

Comment: To follow up on before, how many lines do you expect from `wc -l <fileName`? Also, just to be sure, you're using the single char Ctrl-M (as ^M), not the 2 seperate chars that are visible as '^' 'M'? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I'm expecting 14K+ lines and it's the single character. The same value works fine on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Count lines in a file using PHP](http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file)

```
<?php 
  $file = "somefile.txt"; 

  $lines = count(file($file)); 

  echo "There are $lines lines in $file"; 
?>
```

It even works on files with "DOS" line endings.

Comment: Whoa. Is it _really_ that easy? Can't wait to try this one out, thanks.

Comment: Wow. Looks like it really _is_ that easy. So easy that it never even occurred to me that it c/would be.